Twilio voice call not working in expo react native (IOS)
I have integrated Twilio video call functionality in an expo application in react native. But when trying to integrate the voice it's not working. I have created the voice token from backend and passing it to the frontend mobile application but when using the "voice.connect" no response is getting for me
Backend code:
export const getVoiceAccessToken = async (context: Context, roomName?: string) => {
    try {
        const config = await context.getConfig();
        // Create a "grant" which enables a client to use Voice as a given user
        const voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant({
            outgoingApplicationSid: config.twilioTwimlAppSid,
            incomingAllow: false
        });

        // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
        // containing the grant we just created
        const token = new AccessToken(config.accountSid, config.twilioApiKey, config.twilioAuthtoken, {
            identity: "+916282952623",
            ttl: TOKEN_TTL_IN_SECONDS
        });
        token.addGrant(voiceGrant);

        context.logger.info("createVoiceToken", "voice token created successfully", token.toJwt());
        return token.toJwt();
    } catch (error) {
        context.logger.info("createVoiceToken", "some error occured", error);
    }
};

Frontend code:
const makeCall = async () => {
    if (route.params.token) {
      try {
        console.log("inside makeCall TOKEN:", route.params.token);
        console.log(voice, "voice");
        const outgoingCall = await voice.connect(route.params.token, {
          params: {
            To: "+916282952623",
            recipientType: "ios",
          },
        });
        console.log("Call initiated:", outgoingCall);

        // Handle call events (optional)
        outgoingCall.on(TwilioCall.Event.ConnectFailure, (error) =>
          console.error("ConnectFailure:", error)
        );
        outgoingCall.on(TwilioCall.Event.Reconnecting, (error) =>
          console.error("Reconnecting:", error)
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error making call:", error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("No token available");
    }
  };

In the frontend code I can see the logs till the console before the voice.connect promise but after that no response is getting for me. I have tried with physical device as well.

You just need to add this configuration to your app.json or app.config.js file:
 "ios": {
          ...your_ios_config,
          "infoPlist": {
            "UIBackgroundModes": [
              "audio",
              "fetch",
              "location",
              "remote-notification",
              "voip"
            ],
            "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "This app requires access to the microphone to make voice calls.",
            "com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip": true
          }
        }

